# Jackson 2.2.x: recursive deserialization fails, why?

Tags: java, json, recursion, jackson, json-deserialization

To be precise, this is Jackson 2.2.3.

The deserialization process is quite complicated, since depending on the type of the JSON value I deserialize, the class changes:

- the base, abstract class is `JsonMergePatch`;
- when the JSON value is anything else than a JSON object, I deserialize to `NonObjectMergePatch`;
- otherwise, I recursively deserialize to `ObjectMergePatch`.

Here is the code (imports omitted for "brevity); first, of `JsonMergePatch`:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonMergePatchDeserializer.class)
public abstract class JsonMergePatch
    implements JsonSerializable
{
    public abstract JsonNode apply(final JsonNode input)
        throws JsonPatchException;
}
```

`NonObjectMergePatch`:

```
final class NonObjectMergePatch
    extends JsonMergePatch
{
    private final JsonNode node;

    NonObjectMergePatch(@Nonnull final JsonNode node)
    {
        this.node = Preconditions.checkNotNull(node);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode apply(final JsonNode input)
        throws JsonPatchException
    {
        return null; // TODO!
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        jgen.writeTree(node);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider, final TypeSerializer typeSer)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        serialize(jgen, provider);
    }
}
```

`ObjectMergePatch`:

```
final class ObjectMergePatch
    extends JsonMergePatch
{
    private final Set<String> removedMembers;
    private final Map<String, JsonMergePatch> modifiedMembers;

    ObjectMergePatch(final Set<String> removedMembers,
        final Map<String, JsonMergePatch> modifiedMembers)
    {
        this.removedMembers = ImmutableSet.copyOf(removedMembers);
        this.modifiedMembers = ImmutableMap.copyOf(modifiedMembers);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode apply(final JsonNode input)
        throws JsonPatchException
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        jgen.writeStartObject();

        /*
         * Write removed members as JSON nulls
         */
        for (final String member: removedMembers)
            jgen.writeNullField(member);

        /*
         * Write modified members; delegate to serialization for writing values
         */
        for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonMergePatch> entry:
            modifiedMembers.entrySet()) {
            jgen.writeFieldName(entry.getKey());
            entry.getValue().serialize(jgen, provider);
        }

        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider, final TypeSerializer typeSer)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        serialize(jgen, provider);
    }
}
```

And finally, the custom deserializer:

```
final class JsonMergePatchDeserializer
    extends JsonDeserializer<JsonMergePatch>
{
    @Override
    public JsonMergePatch deserialize(final JsonParser jp,
        final DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        /* FAILS HERE */
        final JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        /*
         * Not an object: the simple case
         */
        if (!node.isObject())
            return new NonObjectMergePatch(node);

        /*
         * The complicated case...
         *
         * We have to build a set of removed members, plus a map of modified
         * members.
         */

        final Set<String> removedMembers = Sets.newHashSet();
        final Map<String, JsonMergePatch> modifiedMembers = Maps.newHashMap();
        final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = node.fields();

        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            entry = iterator.next();
            if (entry.getValue().isNull())
                removedMembers.add(entry.getKey());
            else {
                final JsonMergePatch value 
                    = deserialize(entry.getValue().traverse(), ctxt);
                modifiedMembers.put(entry.getKey(), value);
            }            
        }

        return new ObjectMergePatch(removedMembers, modifiedMembers);
    }

    /*
     * This method MUST be overriden... The default is to return null, which is
     * not what we want.
     */
    @Override
    public JsonMergePatch getNullValue()
    {
        return new NonObjectMergePatch(NullNode.getInstance());
    }
}
```

I have coded tests which work fine as long as the JSON to deserialize is NOT an object; when it is an object, I recursively call the `deserialize()` method to deserialize object member values... But reading the value from the parser fails (marked `/* FAILS HERE */` above) with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the parser, can not deserialize JSON into JsonNode tree
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAsTree(JsonParser.java:1352)
    at com.github.fge.jsonpatch.rfc7386.JsonMergePatchDeserializer.deserialize(JsonMergePatchDeserializer.java:67)
    at com.github.fge.jsonpatch.rfc7386.JsonMergePatchDeserializer.deserialize(JsonMergePatchDeserializer.java:92)
    at com.github.fge.jsonpatch.rfc7386.JsonMergePatchDeserializer.deserialize(JsonMergePatchDeserializer.java:36)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
    at com.github.fge.jsonpatch.rfc7386.SerializationTest.objectSerDeserWorksCorrectly(SerializationTest.java:102)
```

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Uhwell, when googling around, I stumbled upon [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22870488) and came up with an answer; but my word it's ugly...

As the exception mentions, the problem is that the `JsonParser` instance does not have an associated `ObjectCodec`. So, we have to feed it with one; the problem here is why this isn't done automatically...

So, in the custom deserializer, I declared a new `ObjectCodec` as such:

```
// JacksonUtils is a class of mine; the method returns an ObjectMapper,
// which extends ObjectCodec
private static final ObjectCodec CODEC = JacksonUtils.newMapper();
```

and in the `.deserialize()` method, I do:

```
jp.setCodec(CODEC);
```

and it works.

But it's ugly. It sucks. It's terrible. I want a better solution :/

Comment: This should not be necessary, as it would be ugly. Databinding code should be propagate `codec` instance in cases where it has to create temporary parsers for buffered tokens; so it sounds like a bug somewhere. Conversely, if custom deserializer uses buffering, it needs to make sure to pass `JsonParser` for `TokenBuffer`.

Comment: Hmm, so, I use 2.2.3; I have yet to use 2.2.4, would that make a difference?

Comment: Ah. Could well be -- similar issues have been fixed since then. Although I'd try to use up to 2.4.3, if possible and necessary (i.e. if problem persists try to see if later version fixes). 2.4.3 has all relevant fixes that I can think of.