# WAS 9 Start up issue , No ObjectCodec defined for the generator, Jackson 2.5.4

Tags: jackson, websphere

II have created app with REST api which work good with tomact 7 , following are depend ices used

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
         <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
         <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.2</version>
      <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
       </exclusion>

      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

When i deploy this in WAS 9.0.5 it fails giving error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the generator, can only serialize simple wrapper types (type passed java.util.HashMap)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._writeSimpleObject(JsonGenerator.java:1650) ~[jackson-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:317) ~[jackson-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at com.inetpsa.seed.core.internal.DefaultDiagnosticReporter.writeDiagnosticReport(DefaultDiagnosticReporter.java:41) ~[seed-core-support-core-1.4.0-M1.jar:na]
```

Comment: ANyone has idea about it please?

Comment: It is really hard to say what is going there without code samples. Take a look at [How do you set an ObjectCodec on a JsonParser when not going through an ObjectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870488/how-do-you-set-an-objectcodec-on-a-jsonparser-when-not-going-through-an-objectma)

Comment: I dint have any specific written code for this case .. i am using seedstack framework

Comment: WAS 9 has its own JAX-RS . i re bundled my appliation to have same version. It work on tomcat 7 on local

Answer (score 0):

To provide precise solution to the issue is  difficult unless there is code casing the problem.

However, From the exception stack trace it is clear jackson library is being utilized to convert java objects to json .

I am able to reproduce the similar exception stack trace like yours

Likely cause is your are not using

```
    generator.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
```

when trying to covert java objects into  json.

```
    As per the documentation : 

    JsonGenerator setCodec(ObjectCodec oc):

    Method that can be called to set or 
    reset the object to use for writing Java 
    objects as JsonContent (using method 
    writeObject(java.lang.Object)).
```

Sample code to serialize  java objects to json into a file

```
    JsonFactory factory=new JsonFactory();
    JsonGenerator 
    generator=factory.createGenerator(
            new File("computer.json"), 
    JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    generator.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
    generator.writeObject(computer);
    generator.close();
```